# use recordset as criteria in WHERE sql string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to build an sql string to update a table where the field PosSupplierCode  is like the recordset field PosCode from a subform.

I am getting a "Too few parameters. Expected 1" Error.

Have tried all sorts of combinations of ' " () etc but just can't seem to get it right> The code in the WHERE clause was adapted from another answer but isn't doing the job and have tried various others.

```
Sub Update_Records()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String
Dim field

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = Forms!frmProcInvoice!subInvoice.Form.RecordsetClone()



sSQL = "UPDATE tblProducts " & _
        "SET tblProducts.[WholesalePrice] = rs!Cost " & _
        "WHERE (((tblProducts.[PosSupplierCode])='" & (rs!PosCode) & "'));"



rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Three hours chasing down the wrong string! Wonder how many times I got the second place right without realising it was the other one!

Comment: Thank you! Now I can go home at last...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 places with recordset variable. Change also this one:

```
"SET tblProducts.[WholesalePrice] = " & Str(rs!Cost) & " " & _
```

I assumed that Cost is a floating point numeric, so it should have a period as a separator independently of PC regional settings, use `Str` function for this (not `CStr`!)

Comment: Thank you. I'm new here and added comments to my own question.